# Car clutch rpm transfer

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering

Let's say that the engine is spinning at 7000 rpm and the transmission is spinning at 2000 rpm.

How do you calculate the rpm at which the two will meet when the clutch pedal is released and how much rpm will be transferred each second?

Comment: What do you think? What magical source would suddenly change the relative rpm just before contact?  As to **after** making contact, you just have to calculate the frictional force as a function of clutch contact force, fold in the motor torque and the ability of the engine RPM controller (which  might be just the gas pedal) to up the fuel feed; fight that against the opposing inertia of the vehicle's mass-speed as it converts to back-torque  to the gearbox.  It's a problem that cannot be solved analytically.  The engine will slow down and the car  will speed up -- or something will break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a speed-vs-torque curve for the engine, which will generally have a negative slope. Then you need a speed-vs-torque curve for the transmission and whatever load is connected to it, which will generally have a positive slope. Plot both curves on the same graph, and the point where they cross is the RPM you'll have when the clutch is engaged.

If either of the curves is not fixed — e.g., throttle changes on the engine, or tire slippage on the transmission, the problem becomes much more difficult.

In order to determine how the RPMs of the two parts change *as the clutch engages*, you'll need information about the moments of inertia of the various parts, along with data about how the clutch pressure is changing with time.